# (Phonegap / JS) window.close() is not executed using local build

Tags: android, cordova

I have a very bad issue. In fact if I want to build my Phonegap app locally, the app returns always following error on Android:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(http://localhost/?code=4/........)
```

So, the app can get access to localhost - it's right! There is no Web Server. But I've used the loadStart event for closing the window if the InAppBrowser get this error - but why does my device get this error and not the InAppBrowser when I compile this app locally?

```
    $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
    var url = e.originalEvent.url;
    var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
    var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

    if (code || error) {
        //Always close the browser when match is found
        authWindow.close();
    }
```

This example works fine using the cloud-based build. But on my local system it's not working. What can I do for solving this problem?

Regards,
Dennis

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same issue. Please can you suggest me if you resolved this issue.

Comment: Me as well. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you get it solved by now.

In any case, I just found myself in this situation this week when porting an application from 2.x Phonegap version to 3.3.

In my case, the real problem was the InAppBrowser plug-in that was not working at all (no events fired, no nothing). I got it solved by reverting the plugin to an older version (I did it to 0.3.0) by doing:

```
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.3.0
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble on this post, my issue was that I did not include cordova.js in index.html

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in late Feb 2016 / early March 2016... and it was because of a Phonegap InAppBrowser bug that was recently introduced. Please check the version of InAppBrowser that you are using, as it might have the bug where 'loadstart' is not executing with localhost. More info:

https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/02/04/plugins-release.html